# block expression from Sieve of Eratosthenes, twin prime, number of primes in Java

Tags: java, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I need help, do not know how I can correct the error and allow the program to run.
Program is all primes spend 3-12345. Number of primes and twin primes.
All results must be block expression.
I would be thankful for any help!

```
public class SieveOfEratosthenes {

    //final N and byte f[] there is provision must not be changed!

    static final int N = 12345;
    static byte f[] = new byte[(N + 1) / 2];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(sieve());
    System.out.println(twinPrime());
    System.out.println(countPrime());
    }

    private static int sieve() {
    int prime;
    for (int i = 3; i < N; i++)
        return f[i] = false; //cancel all Primzahle
    /*
     * sieves with all primes i, where i is the smallest 
     * prime factor of a composite number j = k*i. 
     * The smallest prime factor of a complex number j 
     * can not be greater than the root of j <= n
     */
    for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(N); i++) {
        do {
        //now i is prime
        return i;

        } while (f[i] = true);
        //and underline its multiples, starting with i * i
        for (int j = i * i; j < N; j++) {
        return f[j] = true;
        }
    }

    //Give the prime numbers greater than n from sqrt. 
    //Thus, those have not yet been deleted

    for (int i = Math.sqrt(N) + 1; i <= N; i++) {
        do {
        return i;

        } while (f[i] = true);
    }
    //now i is prime
    return i = prime;
    }

    //Twin prime
    private static int twinPrime() {
    for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
        if (((6 * n - 1) % 2 != 0) && ((6 * n + 1) % 2 != 0)) {
            //mark all twin prime with "*"
        return Integer.parseInt((n + "*"));
        }
    }
    }

    //Number of primes
    private static int countPrime() {
    return Integer.bitCount(twinPrime());
    }

}
```

Comment: Excuse me for my English, unfortunately I can't do better.

Comment: Please try to post code that is at least compilable. There are for example several type errors with the statement `return f[i] = false;`. Left aside that it does not make sense at all.

Comment: if I knew how I can make it better, than I would not ask for help

Comment: `f[i]` is of type `byte` so you can't assign the `boolean` value `true`. To fix that, you could declare your array as `boolean f[]`. And why do you return from the method here?

Comment: What is the error? (First off: I don't think [return](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) does what you think it does.)

Comment: I know that it does not work. I have tried to implement pseudo code from Wikipedia. This is my result. If you know how to make man better, I like to listen to.

"This field f contains the information from the sieve of Eratosthenes, for the even numbers no place is here provided they are not prime candidates. Use all methods in this field with suitable conversion operations"